# Setting up BIND on OSX, which of these default port configurations is preferrable?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, dns, bind

I'm following [the instructions here](http://www.macshadows.com/kb/index.php?title=How_To:_Enable_BIND_-_Mac_OS_X's_Built-in_DNS_Server) on how to set up BIND on OSX, and I've got as far as [this point](http://www.macshadows.com/kb/index.php?title=How_To:_Enable_BIND_-_Mac_OS_X's_Built-in_DNS_Server#Watch_out.21) (not very far then!)

> Watch out!
>   The rndc-confgen utility is extremely handy for generating new rndc configuration files, but it may set a different default port than named. You can use the following commands to ensure that the port number is the same in both configurations:

```
more /etc/named.conf | grep 'inet.*\?port'
more /etc/rndc.conf | grep '\-port'
```

> If both ports are not the same, it's best to change one before starting BIND.

Um, yes, but which one should I prefer?

```
$ more /etc/named.conf | grep 'inet.*\?port'
inet 127.0.0.1 port 54 allow {any;}
```

or

```
$ more /etc/rndc.conf | grep '\-port'
default-port 953;
```

I've never used BIND before and I've no idea which of these is preferable, and would be grateful for any help or insight.

---

BIND 9.6-ESV-R4-P3
OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://www.geeklan.co.uk/?p=169) and [this one too](http://www.springsurprise.com/2011/10/17/enabling-dns-statistics-for-mac-os-x-server/) it seems that `rndc` sets up its default port on 953, and `named` (the bind9 server) is already set to default to 54. Both articles change the `rndc` default port to 54 in the config.